# if statement to check if mysql row exists, then selecting next query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm attempting to select a query to use based on the number of rows returned by a test result.

```
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']));

    $result = "SELECT FROM Notifications WHERE UserID=$id";
    $r = e_mysql_query($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result); 
    $result = '';

    if ($num_results != 0) {
        $result =
            "SELECT U.UserID,U.FirstName,U.LastName, " .
            " DATE_FORMAT(U.BirthDate,'%m-%d-%Y') AS BirthDate, " .
            " N.Email, N.Phone,N.ProviderName, N.SubNotifications " .
            " FROM Users U, Notifications N " .
            " WHERE U.LocationID=0 " .
            " AND N.UserID='$id'";
    } else  {
        $result =
            "SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName," .
            " DATE_FORMAT(BirthDate, '%m-%d-%Y') AS BirthDate " .
            " FROM Users " .
            " WHERE LocationID = 0 " .
            " AND UserID ='$id'";

    }
    echo $result;
    e_mysql_result($result); //Bastardized/homegrown PDO

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $retValue['userInfo'] = $row;
    ...
```

I'm checking the Notifications table to see if the UserID exists there, if it doesn't it loads what does exist from the Users table, if it does, then it loads everything from the Notifications table.

I'm echoing out the `$result` and the proper statement is loaded, but it doesn't execute. When I run the concatenated query I get from the PHP preview, it returns just fine.

Before I had to if/else this, I was running the first query, loading everything from the Notifications table, and it was loading just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: What means `but it doesn't execute`? How you have checked it?

Comment: I never get the returned array. I've `echo $result` right before I execute and what I get on the Response I can Copy and Paste in mysql cli to get the intended results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the whole thing with one query with a LEFT JOIN.

```
$query= "SELECT U.UserID, U.FirstName,U.LastName,  " .
    " DATE_FORMAT(U.BirthDate,'%m-%d-%Y') AS BirthDate,  " .
    " N.Email, N.Phone,N.ProviderName, N.SubNotifications  " .
    " FROM Users U  " .
    " LEFT JOIN Notifications N  " .
    " ON U.UserID = N.UserID  " .
    " WHERE U.UserID = '$id'";
```

Comment: Will that return the Users set if the Notifications set doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes. That's what LEFT JOIN does. As opposed to INNER JOIN where it only returns results when matching rows exist in both tables.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it existed, just forgot what it was called... I edited it to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing execute a query with **mysql_query()** on all `$result`

Also change (query variable should be quoted) so change your all variables `$id` quoted

```
$result = "SELECT FROM Notifications WHERE UserID=$id";
```

to

```
$result = "SELECT FROM Notifications WHERE UserID='$id'";
$r = mysql_query($result);
```

**Note** :- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: I changed it, and it's a legacy system (har har), so we've added our own homegrown system, e_mysql_*. Jinky, but it works.

Comment: `userInfo` is the array we want it returned to, it's our SOP. `e_mysql_query` is just a wrapper for `mysql_query` with error reporting among other things are head dev threw in. It's not the issue, I use it countless times everyday.

Comment: what is e_mysql_query()? why you not applying it all queries